# Airplane mode as homescreen shortcut?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-pixel, airplane-mode

On Android 12, can I have the Airplane mode button as a homescreen shortcut? I want a way to quickly turn it on, without first swiping down from the top.

Comment: It seems to me you can add a file shortcut to your home screen by long pressing the file and then click on the 3 dots to then add shortcut and choose the location for it, namely your home screen.  Then somehow you edit that shortcut to be a toggle for the ADB commands shown in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130530/use-adb-to-check-if-airplane-mode-is-turned-on/26906472#26906472

Comment: @Archerbob You can not execute adb commands from within a home screen entry. Toggle Airplane mode is pretty complicated on an unrooted phone. See for example this discussion how to do it using Tasker: https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/f27e7x/can_tasker_enable_airplane_mode_when_my_wifi_is/

Comment: @Robert Can you run ADB commands indirectly then? Have the shortcut run another file?

Comment: @Archerbob To my knowledge this is possible in general, but it requires you to connect the phone to a PC and execute same special commands via adb to make it accessible from within an app like Tasker. And you have to do this after every phone reboot.